# How do I make "php extension missing" errors show up

Tags: php, wordpress

Sometimes I encouter the WordPress white screen of death due to a missing extension. Last time it was the WordPress AMP plugin missing the php xml extension. I tried pretty much "everything" I could think of to get a trace in a log, e.g.:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

in wp-config.php. All I got was the dreaded white page. No trace in debug.log or the virtual hosts error log.

What am I missing?

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', true);` may help

Comment: White screen usually means a database issue I find - check and re-check your wp-config etc... also dont use 'WP_DEBUG_LOG' if you want to print to screen.

Comment: you will most probably need to change the values in php.ini, a lot of hosting providers lock ini values. If you have access to httpd.conf (assuming apache) you can change this but why bother? Its just as quick to edit php.ini

Answer (score 0):

To enable error reporting to your php code append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, i.e.:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
//the rest of the code...
```

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL) was in wp-config.php. display_errors is supposed to show the problems in the browser, right? If I remember correctly, I even tried this - nothing showed up. Not on the screen or in a log.

Comment: Yes it is, and it should show any error your script may have,

Comment: Tried "boom();" in index.php. That one shows up in apache error log. The missing extension issue does not. Will resume on Monday. Thanks so far.